# Populating insert values in asp.net dynamic data site?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to create a dynamic data site with scaffolding according to: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-dynamic-data/your-first-scaffold-and-what-is-dynamic-data

The site displays a SQL table with an "Insert New Item" link, which takes you here:
[image]

I have another SQL table which holds some of the information already. I would like to add a function that is called when the user navigates away from the "account" field; the function will query the other SQL table and populate the fields that it already holds for that account.

I'm stuck on where to put the function and how to setup the account field to call it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a couple of years since I did one of these so pardon the details being a bit short.

You can 'override' the default New Item form. In that you can pre-populate the fields with anything you want.  I think you have to take care of the Save also, and of setting out the controls on the form and populating them (you've overridden the generated form after all).

Another possibility is to create a partial class which extends the Model class and populates it in a constructor extension (I remember doing various stuff with this technique). There might also be some extension points on the model Context (or whatever its called) which you can tap into - it's pretty flexible as I remember.